# How to access private photos through Flickrj Api?

Tags: private, photos, flickr, flickrj

I'm making an authenticated call to access photos through Flickr API. But I am only getting my public photos but not any private photos.

Given below is the code I'm using,

```
Flickr f;
 RequestContext requestContext;
 String frob = "";
 String token = "";

 DocumentBuilder xmlParser = null;


 public void getImages() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, FlickrException, URISyntaxException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
 {

  DocumentBuilderFactory dcb = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            this.xmlParser = dcb.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



  f = new Flickr("199d038ad88f6c6c377a4ab2341fb60f","4583b2386d3d6439",new REST()) ;
  Flickr.debugStream = false;
  requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
  AuthInterface authInterface = f.getAuthInterface();
  //PeopleInterface peopleInterface = f.getPeopleInterface();

  try {
  frob = authInterface.getFrob();
  } catch (FlickrException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("frob: " + frob);


  java.net.URL url =authInterface.buildAuthenticationUrl(Permission.READ, frob);

  System.out.println(url.toExternalForm());

  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  desktop.browse(url.toURI());


  // Get the response
  Auth auth = null ;
  String aLine = "";

  while(aLine.equals(""))
  {

   java.io.DataInputStream in = new java.io.DataInputStream(System.in);
   aLine = in.readLine();

  }

  auth =authInterface.getToken(frob);
  System.out.println("auth = "+auth);
  requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
  requestContext.setAuth(auth);
  f.setAuth(auth);

  UrlsInterface urlsInterface = f.getUrlsInterface();
  PhotosInterface photosInterface = f.getPhotosInterface();




  SearchParameters searchParams=new SearchParameters();
     searchParams.setSort(SearchParameters.INTERESTINGNESS_DESC);




     //Execute search with entered tags

     searchParams.setUserId(auth.getUser().getId());


     PhotoList photoList=photosInterface.search(searchParams, 10,1);


     if(photoList!=null){
        //Get search result and check the size of photo result
        for(int i=0;i<photoList.size();i++){
            Photo photo=(Photo)photoList.get(i);

           System.out.println(photo.getSmallSquareUrl());

        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by following a different approach.

This is how i solved this. Instead of using the GET method I used the getList method in photoSetsInterface (photoSetsInterface.getList(auth.getUser().getId()).getPhotosets()) .For this method you can pass the auth_token as an input parameter. Therefore it gives you all the photo sets. Then I took each photoset and retrived images under all privacy levels.

And then you can take all the photos that are not in a set by using the getNotInSet method in PhotosInterface. getNotInSet method returns all the photos not in a set regardless of the privacy level.

You can find the sample code in my [blog](http://kumaripaba.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-access-private-photos-through.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access private data by editing flickrj.

I added the `auth_token` parameter in `com.aetrion.flickr.photos.PhotosInterface`:

```
public PhotoList search(SearchParameters params, int perPage, int page)
    throws IOException, SAXException, FlickrException {
    PhotoList photos = new PhotoList();

    List parameters = new ArrayList();
    parameters.add(new Parameter("method", METHOD_SEARCH));
    parameters.add(new Parameter("api_key", apiKey));

    parameters.addAll(params.getAsParameters());


    if (perPage > 0) {
        parameters.add(new Parameter("per_page", "" + perPage));
    }
    if (page > 0) {
        parameters.add(new Parameter("page", "" + page));
    }
    //
    String token = RequestContext.getRequestContext().getAuth().getToken();
    if (token != null)
      parameters.add(
        new Parameter(
          "auth_token", 
          RequestContext.getRequestContext().getAuth().getToken()
        )
      );
    //
    parameters.add(
        new Parameter(
            "api_sig",
            AuthUtilities.getSignature(sharedSecret, parameters)
        )
    );

    Response response = transport.get(transport.getPath(), parameters);
```

with this change, I was able to get my private photos.

the flickr api docs say, that " *Every authenticated call requires both the* `auth_token` *and* `api_sig` *arguments* ".. and that was missing.

I took the idea from there: [link text](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157624535523789/) and used a servlet to access flickr.

Answer (score 1):

To make authenticated calls with the flickrj api you need, in addition to your apiKey and secret, a third code, the **token**.

We get the token with a one-off first call, and then with the token in hand you can just use the api classes as you'd expect.

If you've ever used a flickr iOS/Android client you will recognise this: the first time you use the app, it sends you to a URL for you to authorise it. What it does is when you authorise it it gets this **token** key, and then its good to go. Without it, its not. Same for your java app.

I used this example implementation for this first step authentication, with a couple of modifications though as I am working in a Spring MVC app, not a desktop app.
Remember that you only run this once, and the only point of this is to get the token key.

https://github.com/mohlendo/flickrj/blob/master/examples/AuthExample.java

Line 55:
`frob = authInterface.getFrob();`

The only purpose of a frob is to use it to construct the authentication URL, see line 60:
`URL url = authInterface.buildAuthenticationUrl(Permission.DELETE, frob);`

I did this in a spring MVC app, not a desktop app, so after line 60 I instead printed the URL to System.out and then paused the programme for a minute with `Thread.sleep(60000);`

That gave me enough time to copy-paste the URL from my console to a browser and click "OK allow my app to use my flickr account".

Straight after that, when the program resumes all I cared was line 70 that prints the token to the console.

With the token in hand, the authorisation is complete and I was set to use the Flickrj api.

With the 3 keys in hand (apiKey, secret, token) here is my Service class with a static method to create a Flickr object.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import com.aetrion.flickr.Flickr;
import com.aetrion.flickr.REST;
import com.aetrion.flickr.RequestContext;
import com.aetrion.flickr.auth.Auth;
import com.aetrion.flickr.auth.Permission;
import com.aetrion.flickr.util.IOUtilities;

public class FlickrjService {

    private static Flickr flickr;

    public static Flickr getFlickr() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        Properties properties;
        try {
            in = FlickrjService.class.getResourceAsStream("/flickrj.properties");
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(in);
        } finally {
            IOUtilities.close(in);
        }

        flickr = new Flickr(properties.getProperty("flickrj.apiKey"), properties.getProperty("flickrj.secret"), new REST("www.flickr.com"));
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
        Auth auth = new Auth();
        auth.setPermission(Permission.READ);
        auth.setToken(properties.getProperty("flickrj.token"));
        requestContext.setAuth(auth);
        Flickr.debugRequest = false;
        Flickr.debugStream = false;
        return flickr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I was having a similar problem with seeing only public photos and have since got it working.

I'd downloaded the flickrapi-1.2.zip from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/flickrj/files/ and was using flickrapi-1.2.jar in my webapp.

Flickr.debugRequest was showing the GET request, but it never included "auth_token", "api_sig", etc. parameters that AuthInterface checkToken (for example) successfully forces on the request.

Anyway, so just today I downloaded the source from:

flickrj.cvs.sourceforge.net/flickrj/

(You can see the revision history at: flickrj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flickrj/api/build.properties?view=log if you're interested.)

I built the jar locally, included that in the web app and could see private photos.

I haven't spent the time to investigate further about what the exact problem was...need to use it for something :)

I don't know if that will help you, but that find is the only thing separating me from insanity.