# How to access private photosets on flickR with Java?

Tags: java, flickr

currently i use the FlickR-API-1.2 for Java to call images from flickR.
The authentification of users works successful, but i can't get private photosets from this users.

What's wrong? I got a token with permission to read.
I call the photosets with:

```java
 Collection<Photoset> sets=photoSetsInterface.getList(auth.getUser().getId()).getPhotosets;
```

The Collection only contains the public sets from this user.

//EDIT: The permission of the the token is read

greetings

Comment: [Ths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289552/how-to-access-private-photos-through-flickrj-api) might help

Comment: Thanks, I'm already find this link and the solution from [this](http://kumaripaba.blogspot.de/2010/10/how-to-access-private-photos-through.html) link. But it doesn't work. If all photosets has the privilege _private_, the size of the collection is 0. Later i will test the solution from the second post.